# How to read and unread Unicode characters from stdin in Rust?

Tags: rust

In C you use `getc` and `ungetc` to read bytes with look ahead for parsers.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Rust with Unicode characters?

I tried `io::stdin().chars()` but there seems to be some kind of problem, I do not understand. The Compiler complains to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `getc()` and `ungetc()` are using a global `FILE *` named `stdin`, this allow then to buffering the input. In rust it's similar, [`stdin.lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) will give you [`StdinLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.StdinLock.html) that implement [`Bufread`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.StdinLock.html#impl-BufRead), AFAIK there is no builtin way to do what you want, people will simply use [`lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines). Also, your requirement is more hard than it's look, you ask for unicode stream, while your C function doesn't care about this.

So here a basic solution:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut stdin = stdin.lock();

    while let Ok(buffer) = stdin.fill_buf() {
        let (input, to_consume) = match str::from_utf8(buffer) {
            Ok(input) => (input, input.len()),
            Err(e) => {
                let to_consume = e.valid_up_to();
                if to_consume == 0 {
                    break;
                }
                let input = unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(&buffer[..to_consume]) };
                (input, to_consume)
            }
        };

        println!("{}", input);

        // here you could do many thing like .chars()

        stdin.consume(to_consume);
    }
}
```